# Can I execute a code block in org-mode without exporting it?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I was following [this blog](https://github.com/vikasrawal/orgpaper/blob/master/orgpapers.org) about using org-mode for writing papers, and the author said

> Use C-c C-e l l to create a LaTeX file. Then, **from the terminal**, use
>   Pandoc as follows to create an odt or a docx file.

```
pandoc --bibliography=biblidatabase.bib --filter pandoc-citeproc \
latexfile.tex -o outputfile.odt
```

*Is it possible to run this shell command within the same org document?*

I tried to add a bash source code block in the `.org` file:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC bash
    pandoc --bibliography=biblidatabase.bib --filter pandoc-citeproc \
    latexfile.tex -o outputfile.odt
#+END_SRC
```

But then, this code block showed up in the exported `.odt` file. This is expected, but of course, I don't want this shell command (*or its output*) in the final paper.

*Would it be possible to suppress this code block during the export and prevent it from showing up in the exported file?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `:exports none` should take care of that:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC bash :exports none
    pandoc --bibliography=biblidatabase.bib --filter pandoc-citeproc \
    latexfile.tex -o outputfile.odt
#+END_SRC
```

See [Exporting Code Blocks](https://orgmode.org/manual/Exporting-Code-Blocks.html#Exporting-Code-Blocks) in the manual.